# Algorithm to check whether distance between any two objects is within the Specified grid

Tags: geometry, 2d

I have distance value between two objects. Need algorithm to check whether measured distanced is available in distance of any two objects in grid pattern shown in Image
[Grid for verification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pvKs.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is grid with squared cells. All distances at such grid (expressed in units of cell size)  should satisfy to condition

```
d^2 = a^2 + b^2
```

If  squared distance is integer and you can represent it as sum of two integer squares, then objects can be placed in grid nodes.

There is [mathematical criteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem) - number `P` is not representable as sum of two squares if it's factorization into primes contains any `(4n+3)`factor in odd power

Comment: Thanks MBo, Understand part of answer. It is applicable, if second object is at in EXACT pitch (in X & Y (Horizontal & Vertical) direction). But if second object is at Half (or in multiple of half) the pitch value then it is problem.

Comment: But you have not mentioned "half-way" objects. If the second object always lies in K*size or (K+1/2)*size positions (no 1/3, 1/17 and so on) - just make grid size/2